# How should I test a public method that access a private member

Tags: c#, nunit

So I have something along the lines of this

```
private List<ConcurrentQueue<int>> listOfQueues = new List<ConcurrentQueue<int>>()
public void InsertInt(int id, int value)
{
    listOfQueues[id].Enqueue(value);
}
```

Is this something I shouldn't be unit testing?
If it is how do I test the InsertInt method without using any other methods?
is it ok to use the method to retrieve the data from the queue to test if the it was enter correctly?
Is this something I should be using mocks for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally do not want to test private members.  The point of unit testing is that from the outside, the class takes the specified inputs and (when requested) will give you the correct outputs.  You don't care about the implementation of HOW it gives you those outputs, you just care that it gives you the correct outputs for external usage.

To show this, say you create a unit test verifies that your `InsertInt()` method inserts the int to `listOfQueues`.  Then your requirements change, and you have to change your implementation strategy, and instead of using a `List<ConcurrentQueue<int>>` it becomes a `Dictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<int>>`.  This may not actually require a change to your inputs, and your outputs can still pass any output verification, but your `InsertInt()` unit test will fail because it's hard coded to the implementation.

The better idea is to do unit tests that makes sure that if you call `InsertInt()` with the correct input, that your output methods will still return the corrected output, as well as creating unit tests that calling `InsertInt()` with invalid parameters causes exceptions.  You can then change everything about your internal implementation and be confident that your class is still working correctly.  Unit testing the implementation adds extra over-head while providing very little benefit in testability.

Note that I am NOT saying that this method should not be unit tested, it's just that the unit tests need to be developed in a way that reflects how outside objects will interact with your class.

Comment: So its better to test multiple things in one unit test, than to tie the unit test to an implementation?

Comment: Yes, I believe so because it's mimicking exactly how that one class will be used in real-world usage scenarios.  If you test the two methods independently you do not have a unit test that makes sure that the input and output methods are actually working together, it's just an assumption.  You can then change the implementation (and test) of one and while your unit tests will pass but the code will fail in production.  You still need to unit test that if you call the input method with x parameters your output gives you y parameters, thus private testing was a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Also, it's still unit testing because your unit test is only dealing with the one class itself and not going outside of the class, so dealing with multiple methods isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should unit test it. You can use a private accessor to get the listOfQueues.
You must make sure with a unit test that the method behaves as expected with exceptions and that the item really is inserted.

Check out this article on how to unit test private methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184807(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Following the article listed will result in visual studio asking if you would like a private accesser added to the assembly.  You can do this manually by adding the following line to you AssemblyInfo.cs page [assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("<name of testing assembly>")]

Comment: InternalsVisibleTo only makes internals visible - not private?  The article above generates reflection wrappers around private methods which you can then compile in to your test assembly.

Comment: is there a way to generate a private accessor for a member not a method?

Comment: @scott I haven't tested this, but check out this link http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/29/unit-testing-exposing-private-members.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As this method is a public method, it needs to be unit tested.

A quick look at your method would reveal that passing `-1` as the value of `id` would cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. This would have been realized during coding if the unit test case for this method had been designed (assuming that many such methods exist).

To check whether the insertion is successful, you can use the method pointed out by @Oskar Kjellin.

If you want to get dirty, then you can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx), to check whether the value has been inserted or not.

```
// Sample with Queue instead of ConcurrentQueue
private void TestInsertInt(int id, int value)
{
    myInstance.InsertInt(id, value);

    FieldInfo field = myInstance.GetType().GetField("listOfQueues", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    List<Queue<int>> listOfQueues = field.GetValue(myInstance) as List<Queue<int>>;
    int lastInserted = listOfQueues[id].Last();

    Assert.AreEqual(lastInserted, value);
}
```

Comment: that's what I felt too. So i guess the more important question is what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to unit test private members to create a unit test that passing in an id of zero will cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 1):

You should not be testing the behaviour of the queues - this is an implementation detail that you could change without changing the behaviour of the method. for example, you could replace the ConcurrentQueue with another data structure, perhaps a tree, without needing to update the unit tests.

What you are testing is that this method accepts the inputs and stores the value as you expect. Therefore you will need some way of interrogating the state of the system such as

```
public int GetInt(int id)
```

Then you test that the method inserts as you expect by retrieving them using the same id.

You should test that the public method returns the results you expect in every case you can think of, and leave it to the method to store the values as it sees fit. Therefore I would probably test the method like this, with different inputs :

```
        [TestCase(1,2,3)] // whatever test cases make sense for you
        [TestCase(4,5,6)]
        [TestCase(7,8,9)]
        [Test]
        public void Test_InsertInt_OK( int testId, int testValue, int expectedValue)
        {
            InsertInt(testId, testValue);
            Assert.AreEqual( GetInt(testId), expectedValue )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something I shouldn't be unit
>   testing?

If you are targeting 100% test coverage then yes

> If it is how do I test the InsertInt
>   method without using any other
>   methods?

Several options:

- Use a different accessor method as
  you suggest.
- Make the container internal and give the unit test assembly access to internals
- Factor the container out into a separate class which you pass as a dependency to this class and then in your unit test pass a mock container instead
- Use reflection to access the private members

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to use the [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Personally, I would either use DI(Dependency Injection) or make the `private`, `internal` for the sake of Unit Testing!